# Trino on pure AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, trino, data-lake

Is it possible to run Trino on top of pure AWS S3 without any other additional engine? In the Trino connectors there is no S3, but in the docs it is mentioned it could be run over S3 or e.g. Hive. So do I need some layer over S3 such as Hadoop/Hive or something like that, or it is possible to use Trino just with S3 as is?

Comment: Did you find a solution that does not require a hive metastore?

Comment: No. You need some sort of metastore being it Hive or others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trino can use S3 as a storage mechanism through the [Hive connector](https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/hive-s3.html).  But S3 itself is only for object (basically files) storage - there is not a server type component.  You must have a [server process](https://trino.io/docs/current/installation.html) running somewhere as either a Linux process or a Docker image.

Comment: Thank you. Do I also need something as a “middlelayer” between S3 and Trino? Some metastore? I. e. Aws Data Catalog or Hive itself?

Comment: There isn't a layer so much as the configuration of the Hive connector.  Take a look at that first link - there are a bunch of config parameters to get setup.